# Css problems with positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, css-position

I have included 2 photos and my css code below. I am trying to bring my #bottomBar up so its directly under and that its the same width as the black space - you can see in the images below.

Depending on if i use position relative or position absolute i get the desired affect of either being directly under the black space or being the same width. But never both at the same time.

I am using a bootstrap templet in my html, would that cause the issues that i am getting?

[css position relative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TRRk.png)

[css position absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M63n.png)

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.container{
 padding: 0;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: black;
}
#header{
 display: flex;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10vh;
 background: linear-gradient(to right,white, #a5c6ff, #0066ff);
}
h1{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 6vw;
}
#img{
 width: 15vw;
}
.navbar{
 padding: 5px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right,white, #a5c6ff, #0066ff);
}
.navbar-toggler{
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 10vw;
 height: 4vh;
 
}
.navbar-toggler-icon{
 height: 3vh;
 width: 9vw;
 margin: auto;
}
#bottomBar{
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The issue is not bootstrap, when you position an element absolutely you basically take it out of the document flow, so it's in a sense on top of everything else, ignoring the containers you have previously set up

Comment: That doesn’t really answer my question though. Why is position relative causing the problem I am getting in the picture above. How do I find a solution to the problem I am getting?

Comment: Can you send your HTML code for checking position relative and position absolute is working or not?